# Calling REST service on tomcat startup

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I need to call a REST service, deployed on Tomcat, during startup. The problem is that this service is running at the same Tomcat from where I try to invoke it. During startup http-nio handler is not accessible (his intitialization is finished at the end of server starting) so calling REST service hangs server. Is there any possibility to start http-nio at the begining of Tomcat startup instead at the end? Or maybe there is a possibility to call java method after server startup (now I'm calling service at PostConstruct method)?

Comment: Possibly this requirement is a **design** problem. Maybe you should check your **application architecture**. Additionally, the call you mentioned can run with the first request of the user or via a scheduled process.

Comment: Are you using any higher level framework on top of Tomcat or just a plain webapp with servlets?

Comment: Webapp with servlets. I'm also using Spring.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think you need to do this and what problem is this supposed to solve. That way the answers can concentrate on the real problem and not on what you think appears to be the solution.

Comment: Ok. I have few applications, which are running on differents Tomcats. In database I'm storing addresses to REST services running at these applications. During starting Tomcat (or after startup) I want to call these addresses and get some information from them. There is a case where REST service is deployed on the same server on which I try to invoke all services. Maybe solution with scheduled proccess is a good clue, because I'm considering checking availability of these services periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Async Http Client .

AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setRequestTimeout(60000).build())

with @Scheduled of spring